# How to flow type annotate a default object export?

Tags: flowtype, es6-modules

Consider:

```
/* @flow */
export default {test: true};
```

How best to flowtype this?

The only way I've found is:

```
/* @flow */
const data : {test: boolean} = {test: true};
export default data;
```

Is there not a way to do this inline without the const definition?

Background: While flow could infer the definitiion of the object, in my case it's a 200kb large object containing a dataset that is written to the file by a build tool. So I wanted to add a flow type to assist developers in readability, and also that the object doesn't have all keys depending on the content of the underlying dataset, so the flow type would still document those optional keys.

Comment: Flow should be able to retrieve the type information without the definition itself. The assignment of the data variable should be enough. So you could possibly write the following code: export default { test: true }; But I haven't tried this code snipped because I'm on my phone :p

Comment: Thanks @JanPeter - I edited question that the data in my case is large and not readable. Wanted to use flow as a kind of auto-document.

Comment: Ah okey, you could use a cast if you don't want to use the `const` . Like this:
`export default ({ test: true }: {test:boolean});` . I think that's the shortest way of writing it.

Comment: Ah bingo @JanPeter - so simple. That's my answer!

Comment: Should I add this as an answer? So people also searching for this problem don't need to look at the comments? Because who reads comments anyway? :P

Comment: Yeh do it @JanPeter, get the points. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way to add a type definition to your problem is a cast in flow like the following:

```
export default ({ test: true }: {test: boolean});
```